# jQuery Add click event if cursor between coordinates

Tags: jquery, position, swap, coords

If I have to following HTML which is a image of a map. The map is divided into colour areas. My goal is if the cursor is over an area of the image, to swap the image.

```
<div id="map" class="mouse-click"><img class="image-swap" src="images/map.png" /></div>
```

I can find the  X Y Coords with

```
$('#map').mousemove(function(e){
    var x = e.clientX - this.offsetLeft;
    var y = e.clientY - this.offsetTop;
    $('#map-xy').html("X: " + x + " Y: " + y); 
});
```

How do I add a click event to swap the img if the cursor is between a set of coordinates.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#map').on('click', function(e){
    var x = e.clientX - this.offsetLeft,
        y = e.clientY - this.offsetTop;
    if (x > xMin && x < xMax && y > yMin && y < yMax) {
        // click was in target zone, swap img
    }
});
```

Where `xMin`, `xMin`, `yMax`, and `yMin` describe the boundaries of the target area.

Comment: Please excuse my lack of knowledge

Thanks but I can't get it to work  :-(. Where am I going wrong?

    if (x > 708 && x < 751 && y > 470 && y < 573) {
        
  
    $('div#map > img').mouseover(function(){
    $(this).attr('src', 'images/map_hover.png');
     });
    $('div#map > img').mouseout(function(){
    $(this).attr('src', 'images/map.png');
     });

Comment: Try this: [http://pastebin.com/ha8rCbNv](http://pastebin.com/ha8rCbNv). Make sure that you are using jQuery 1.7+ and check your JS Console for any errors.

Comment: One more question and I'll be done for this question if I want to change $('#map').on('click', function(e){ to a mouseover event, and I have tried a few ways, non successful how would I achieve that> $('#map').on('mouseover', function(e){ or $('#map').on('hover', function(e){

Comment: `$('#map').on('mouseover', function(e) {` is correct. I'm not sure why that wouldn't be working...

Comment: //Blue green
$('#map').on('click', function(e){
    var x = e.clientX - this.offsetLeft,
        y = e.clientY - this.offsetTop;
    if (x > 617 && x < 947 && y > 486 && y < 567) {
        $(this).children('img').attr('src', '/javascripts/images/map-blue-green-shadow.png');
  $('div.popme').show();

    }
});


//Orange
$('#map').on('mouseover', function(e){
    var x = e.clientX - this.offsetLeft,
        y = e.clientY - this.offsetTop;
    if (x > 617 && x < 953 && y > 585 && y < 701) {
        $(this).children('img').attr('src', '/javascripts/images/map-orange-shadow.png');
    }
});

Comment: Wait, try `mousemove` instead of `mouseover`. I think the `mouseover` event doesn't include client coords.

Comment: Thats it, once again you're a winner. Thank-you ever so much for the help. Much appreciated....Grovel Grovel :)